# Why wont doubles multiply? (Java)

Tags: java, double, pong

I am trying to create Pong, and am making the physics for the ball.

I have the following code:

```
public Ball(Pong pong) {
        random = new Random();
        this.x = pong.width / 2 - this.width / 2;
        this.y = pong.height / 2 - this.height / 2;

        this.pong = pong;

        this.motionX = 2.0;

        this.motionY = random.nextDouble();
        while (this.motionY > 0.7) {
            this.motionY = random.nextDouble();
            System.out.println(motionY);
        }



        multiplier = 8 / this.motionX;
        System.out.println(motionX);
        this.motionX = multiplier * motionX;
        System.out.println(motionX);
        this.motionY *= multiplier;


}

public void update(Paddle paddle1, Paddle paddle2) {
    this.x += this.motionX;
    this.y += this.motionY;

}

public void render(Graphics2D g) {

    Graphics2D gg = (Graphics2D) g;

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    Ellipse2D.Double shape = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, width, height);
    g.fill(shape);
}
```

In the Ball method, I have set motionX to 2.0. Later on in the method I times motionX by multiplier, so I can make all ball speeds the same. However, what should be 2.0 * 8.0 (16.0) it comes out with 8.0. This happens with every number.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: just a side-note, but why do you use a while-loop to get a value for `motionY` that is smaller than 0.7? just multiply with 0.7 and leave the loop away. More efficient, better style,...

Comment: Just a point: Instead of put `[Solved]` in your question mark the answer that had been more helpful for you as accepted (on the left of the answers you have a tick, just press it to mark your favourite answer as accepted) :)

Answer (score 3):

Your multiplier is not 8... it is 8 divided by `motionX` so of course if you multiply back by `motionX` it is going to cancel out the denominator. Here is what you are doing :

```
x = 2
m = 8 / x
x = m * x = 8 / x * x = 8
```

Answer (score 1):

But

`this.motionX = 2.0;`

then

`multiplier = 8 / this.motionX;`

then

`this.motionX = multiplier * motionX;`

it's looks like motionX is an 8 to me.

Comment: What I was trying to do was make it go the other way (negative x), but the multiplied motionX was always going the positive way. I thought this was a problem with using doubles but I have managed to solve now.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution to my (silly) error:**

I was dividing a number and then multiplying it back.

**Solution to my physics problem (making the ball go left and right on the table):**

Changed the Ball method to this:

```
public Ball(Pong pong) {
        random = new Random();
        this.x = pong.width / 2 - this.width / 2;
        this.y = pong.height / 2 - this.height / 2;

        this.pong = pong;

        this.motionX = random.nextInt(3) -1;
        while (motionX == 0) {
            this.motionX = random.nextInt(3) -1;
        }

        System.out.println(motionX);


 this.motionY = random.nextDouble();
    while (this.motionY > 0.7) {
        this.motionY = random.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(motionY);
    }

    multiplier = 8.0 / this.motionX;
    if (this.motionX < 0) {
        this.motionX = -(multiplier * motionX);
    }
    else {
        this.motionX = multiplier * motionX;
    }

    this.motionY *= multiplier;


}
```

I firstly made sure that the motionX could not be 0 (otherwise the ball would not move left or right).

I then added that if the original motionX was negative, it multiplied by the multiplier and *then* changed to a negative.

Thanks for help :)